# Copy a certain string from excel cells in one column to another

Tags: excel, vba, search

[image]i have a column that contains a string "Assigned group: xxxxxxx" . here xxxxx is the value written infront. in each cell in a column say A it contains two to three parameters and Assigned group is one of them. if cannot figure out how can i copy the value written ahead of assigned group to another column for each cell in the column A. PLEASE HELP.
Thankyou

Comment: Can you give an example of full content of what is written in a cell, including other parameters also.

Comment: you could do an if statement followed by left or mid and use search to find the space, you would need to give a more thorough example, seems to me like this can be done with a formula.

Comment: Does the `xxxxx` always be `xxxxx` or could be `xx xxx` or something like that with spaces

Comment: @ChrisHarper i have added an image of the column, in this column i want the value of assignee group that is written in front.

Thankyou for the response it is much appreciated

Comment: @GowthamShiva Please refer to the screenshot, the placement of assignee group string that i want can be jumbled.

Comment: You have to decide on some sort of rule, for the ending of you *Asignee Group*. It could be a line break, or where the *Assign Time* begins. But you near a clear begining and end, if you want to snip out a piece of a string.

Comment: @DilpreetSinghੴ Search for assigned group and assigned time to trim the text what you want. Let me know if you face difficulties

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula in B1 cell and drag it down

`=MID(A1,SEARCH(":",A1,SEARCH("Assignee Group:",A1))+2,IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),A1,SEARCH("Assignee Group:",A1)),LEN(A1))-SEARCH(":",A1,SEARCH("Assignee Group:",A1))-1)`

Comment: Hi Chris thanks man you are a life saver. Can you please explain this to me a bit. how you did it and how can i implement it in vba